# Any know the reason xmlReader/xmlWriter only provide Create method rather than constructors

Tags: c#, .net

Just interesting to know. Why the constructors are protected for those classes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because XmlReader/XmlWriter are abstract classes and it doesn't make much sense to have a public constructor in an abstract class. This is a common factory pattern. You use the static `Create` method which will return a proper implementation based on the argument types in a way that is completely transparent to the developer.

Answer (score 1):

There are specialized types of XMLReader classes like Dictionary Readers, TextReaders etc. that derive from the abstract XMLReader class. You can instantiate those.